# Batch split JPEG using ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, dos

I use the following command to crop and split a jpg names page000.jpg in a folder producing two files

```
convert page000.jpg -crop 2x1@ +repage -colorspace gray ^
        +dither -colors 4 page000_%d.jpg
```

The two parts will be named page000_0.jpg and page000_1.jpg

It works well, but I would like to rewrite this code to work on every JPEG in a catalog.

I wrote this batch code for DOS (.bat):

```
mkdir split
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO xcopy %%f split\
cd split
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO convert %%f -crop 2x1@ +repage -colorspace gray ^
                              +dither -colors 4 %%f_%d.jpg
```

However, it fails to work.

Comment: You should describe more precisely what exactly "fails to work". Without more details, your question is likely to be downvoted and eventually even closed and removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the percent signs that need to be interpreted not by the batch parser but by the convert parser.

```dos
set "parameters=-crop 2x1@ +repage -colorspace gray +dither -colors 4"
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO convert "%%f" %parameters% "%%~nf_%%d.jpg"
                                                        ^^ the escaped percent sign
```

BUT, as the `for` command does not use a static list of files (the list is retrieved while the `for` command iterates), the files generated in the process can be also processed. To solve it you can

1 - Use a static list changing your `for` command into an `for /f` command to first retrieve the list of files using a `dir` command

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do .....
```

2 - Process the input files from original directory and place the output in the `split` directory. That way, as the generated files are not placed in the same folder being processed, they are not detected.

```dos
mkdir split
set "parameters=-crop 2x1@ +repage -colorspace gray +dither -colors 4"
FOR %%f IN (*.jpg) DO convert "%%f" %parameters% "split\%%~nf_%%d.jpg"
```

Comment: It works, however, what I get is 00314.jpg_0.jpg instead of 00314_0.jpg

Comment: @menteith, see the updated answer. I forget to include the  `%~nf`, that is, only the name (without extension) of the file being processed

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy the files to the `split` subdirectory, you can get `convert` to read them from where they are:

```
for %f in (*.jpg) do convert %f -crop 2x1@ +repage -colorspace gray +dither -colors 4 split/%~nf_%d.jpg
```